# Jest webpack 4 babel 7 syntaxError 'import' inside .test.js files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, jestjs, babeljs

**Setup**

> react 16.4.2 (not cra, homebrewed)
>   babel v7
>   jest v24
>   webpack v4.17

PROBLEM
getting error below when I use '`import`' syntax inside my test files (i.e. inside `component.test.js`).

How can I tell Jest to parse the test files using `es6`?

Have done a lot of googling but no joy

```
    C:\repos\sandbox\my_react_starter\src\temp.test.js:2
    import React from 'react';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:471:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:513:25)
```

> jest config:

```
  "jest": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "verbose": true,
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
      ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-css-modules-transform"
    }
  },
```

> .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/react"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

> webpack:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: { path: __dirname + '/dist', publicPath: '/', filename: 'bundle.js' },
    devServer: { contentBase: './dist' },
    module:
    {
        rules:
            [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: { presets: ['es2015'] }
                    }
                }
            ]
    }
};
```

Comment: try including the js files as well in the transform ->  "^.+\\.jsx|js?$": "babel-jest",

Comment: worked! cant believe i missed that. thanks